# {{,}} or the trollolo set

Tags: set-theory

In naive set theory, *everything* may be member of a set. $\{\{,\}\}$ heavily abuses this by using things that are meant only for syntax (the comma, the curly brackets) as elements, thus making the whole thing ambiguous (it could denote the set of the set with the comma or the set containing a left and a right curly bracket). What is the cleanest definitoric way to deal with such syntax abuse?

Comment: The cleanest way to deal with syntax abuse is to disallow it in the logic. Before even defining what the deduction rules or axioms of your logic are, you define what logical sentences are well-formed. Set theory is done on a language that doesn't parse $\{ \{ , \} \}$ as valid.

Comment: I don't know if this is a matter of definition or convention, but I would simply say "don't use single punctuation characters to denote a set", so `{` and `}` and `,` would never make any sense in isolation as sets.

Comment: The way I learned naive set theory, the only things that could be members of sets were other sets, not "everything".

Comment: @JonathanZ: In math, I'm much more naive than any set theory, so the wording might have lacked rigor, especially as I made up that set being a very young pupil :-) In any case, I find Jean's suggestion the most convincing approach.

Comment: Yeah, their observation that you can catch this early, at the syntax/parsing stage seems the most pertinent. I just wanted to point out that set theory isn't quite as free-wheeling as your opening sentence indicated.

Comment: @JonathanZ In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_set_theory#Sets,_membership_and_equality) one can read “In naive set theory, a set is described as a well-defined collection of objects. These objects are called the elements or members of the set. Objects can be anything: numbers, people, other sets, etc.”. But that also says “Naive set theory” can mean various theories, so maybe some allow less; also “well-defined” imposes some limitations. The problem is indeed notational: a set might contain characters, but we should denote them differently, for example as {{“,”}} or {“{”,“}”}.

Comment: P.S. Here an experiment in a very well thought out language (MATHEMATICA): {{","}} is OK and {"{","}"}) too, both even give different out[] (due to a blank after a "real" comma), {{,}} is OK but with warning and parses as {{Null,Null}}.